# 'Unable to open FTDI Deivce tried: 'Quad RS232-HS' and 'Quad RS232-HS A''

Tags: debugging, serial-port, ftdi

I have used ftdi drivers to connect to our test boards many times, using the same README file that was written by my colleague years ago. I have applied the same procedure for ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 with no problem. But when I tried to do the same for ubuntu 22.04, it doesn't seem to work and I get this error message. (for the ocdf command which is an aliase `alias ocdf='sudo rmmod ftdi_sio; openocd64_ab_fpga -f ab_fpga.cfg'`)

```
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
Info : Aldebaran JTAG 15000 kHz
Warn : Unable to open FTDI Device tried: 'Quad RS232-HS' and 'Quad RS232-HS A'
Error: unable to open ftdi device: 2
Runtime Error: /opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/ab_fpga.cfg:39: 
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 58
in procedure 'init' called at file "/opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/ab_fpga.cfg", line 39
```

I could later see `ftdi device 2` is ft2232(if I give false name, it lists the debug interfaces. number 2 is ft2232). I tried re-installing libftdi1 and libftdi1-2 to no avail. This is the content of ab_fpga.cfg file.

```
telnet_port 4444
gdb_port 3333
gdb_memory_map enable
gdb_flash_program enable

interface ft2232
ft2232_device_desc "Quad RS232-HS A"
ft2232_layout usbjtag
ft2232_vid_pid 0x0403 0x6011
adapter_khz 15000


jtag newtap aldebaranv8 cpu -irlen 8 -ircapture 1 -irmask 0xff -expected-id 0xe0a7345f
target create aldebaranv8.cpu aldebaranv8 -endian big -chain-position aldebaranv8.cpu -variant lm3s
aldebaranv8.cpu configure -work-area-virt 0 -work-area-phys 0x10000000 -work-area-size 0x1000000 -work-area-backup 0
init
source /opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/sjtag_fpga.tcl
```

What can I try? I tried to install old version of libftdi but couldn't find it by `apt-get search ftdi` command.

ADD :
Having found that ubuntu provides openocd package, I tried installing it using `sudo apt install openocd` and using the instlled version.  Here is the output with debug info.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu-22 ~/Desktop $ openocd -f ab_fpga.cfg -s /opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/ -d3
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
User : 13 2 options.c:63 configuration_output_handler(): debug_level: 3
User : 14 2 options.c:63 configuration_output_handler(): 
Debug: 15 2 options.c:244 add_default_dirs(): bindir=/usr/bin
Debug: 16 2 options.c:245 add_default_dirs(): pkgdatadir=/usr/share/openocd
Debug: 17 2 options.c:246 add_default_dirs(): exepath=/usr/bin
Debug: 18 2 options.c:247 add_default_dirs(): bin2data=../share/openocd
Debug: 19 2 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /home/ckim/.config/openocd
Debug: 20 2 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /home/ckim/.openocd
Debug: 21 2 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/bin/../share/openocd/site
Debug: 22 2 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/bin/../share/openocd/scripts
Debug: 23 2 configuration.c:97 find_file(): found /opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts//ab_fpga.cfg
Debug: 24 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - telnet_port 4444
Debug: 26 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - gdb_port 3333
Debug: 28 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - gdb_memory_map enable
Debug: 30 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - gdb_flash_program enable
Debug: 32 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - echo DEPRECATED! use 'adapter driver' not 'interface'
User : 34 2 command.c:769 jim_echo(): DEPRECATED! use 'adapter driver' not 'interface'
Debug: 35 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - adapter driver ft2232
Error: 37 2 adapter.c:135 handle_adapter_driver_command(): The specified debug interface was not found (ft2232)
Debug: 38 2 command.c:628 run_command(): Command 'adapter driver' failed with error code -101
User : 39 2 command.c:694 command_run_line(): The following debug adapters are available:
1: parport
2: dummy
3: ftdi
4: usb_blaster
5: ft232r
6: amt_jtagaccel
7: gw16012
8: presto
9: usbprog
10: openjtag
11: jlink
12: vsllink
13: rlink
14: ulink
15: arm-jtag-ew
16: buspirate
17: remote_bitbang
18: hla
19: osbdm
20: opendous
21: sysfsgpio
22: linuxgpiod
23: aice
24: cmsis-dap
25: kitprog
26: xds110
27: st-link
```

So the main problem is : Error: 37 2 adapter.c:135 handle_adapter_driver_command(): The specified debug interface was not found (ft2232)